# Automapper with c#

Tags: c#, entity-framework, rest, asp.net-web-api, automapper

I am trying to increase performance of my api with automapper. I have created the destination DTO and i have a source mnodel already. I've also created the mapping but when i map this error.

```
 The type arguments for method 'Enumerable.Select<TSource, TResult> 
 (IEnumerable<TSource>, Func<TSource, TResult>)' cannot be inferred from the 
 usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.
```

See code sample below

```
  [Route("StaffInfo/{*job_title}")]
    public IHttpActionResult GetStaffInfoByTitle(string job_title)
    {

        var rStructure = _context.employeeinfo.Where(e => e.jobtitle.Contains(job_title)).ToList()
                         .Select(Mapper.Map<employeeinfo, employeeinfoDto>);




        if (rStructure == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        return Ok(rStructure);
    }
```

DTO model

```
    public class employeeinfoDto
   {
    public string employee_number { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string companyname { get; set; }
    public int employee_id { get; set; }
    public Byte? linemanager { get; set; }
   }
```

Domian model

```
    public class employeeinfo
    {  
     public string employee_number { get; set; }
     public string name { get; set; }
     public string companyname { get; set; }
     public int employee_id { get; set; }
     public Byte? linemanager { get; set; }
    }
```

Mapping profile

```
  Mapper.CreateMap<employeeinfo, employeeinfoDto>();
```

Comment: The answer is in the error. Or try to specify a lambda.

Comment: but i am using automapper which should do that automatically right?

Comment: "increase performance" is not one of the claims of automapper. Increase w/respect to what?  Manual copying will always be fastest.

Comment: @gbubemismith it should, so the types aren't what you expect them to be. Ie. `new List<employeeinfo>().Select(Mapper.Map<employeeinfo, employeeinfoDto>)` seems to work just fine for me. Specifying either the types or the lambda will reveil the underlying problem.

Comment: Yes, check all your assumptions. You may have created a new class instead of adding a using somewhere, `Ctrl+.` will do that.

Comment: Side note: use standard naming cvonventions. Types start with a capital, even in Java[Script].

Answer (score -1):

You can use the Queryable Extensions like so:

```
var rStructure = _context.employeeinfo.Where(e => e.jobtitle.Contains(job_title))
                     .ProjectTo<employeeinfoDto>().ToList();
```